# split ArrayList String

Tags: java

how do I split arrayList String 
SCHOOLWORK 
BALCONY 
INSIST 
SALTPETER 
BOLTON 
KITSCHY 
CLIENTELE

I want to split those words to "SCH", "OOL", "WO", "RK".

Here is my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HW2 {

    public static ArrayList<String> getTiles(ArrayList<String> input_list_of_strings) {
        // create a substring by go through the loop first, then .... (instruction)
        Object[] subString = new Object[input_list_of_strings.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < input_list_of_strings.size(); i++) {
            subString[i] = input_list_of_strings.get(i);
            // test just want to see if subString get all String
//          System.out.println(subString[i]);

            String delim=" ";
            String[] splitstrings = ((String) subString[i]).split(delim);
            for (int j = 0; j < splitstrings.length; j++) {
                splitstrings[j] +=delim;
                System.out.println(splitstrings[j]);
            }
        }
        return input_list_of_strings;       
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> input_words = new ArrayList<String>();
        input_words.add("SCHOOLWORK");
        input_words.add("BALCONY");
        input_words.add("INSIST");
        input_words.add("SALTPETER");
        input_words.add("BOLTON");
        input_words.add("KITSCHY");
        input_words.add("CLIENTELE");
        System.out.print(getTiles(input_words));    
    }

}
```

Thank you...

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem? What should be the exact criterion to split a string?

Comment: What should be the exact criterion to split a string?

Comment: What's the deciding factor how you'll break the words apart? There really isn't any intuitive way for me to know you want `SCHOOLWORK` split to `SCH`, `OOL`, `WO`, `RK` instead of, say, `SCHOOL`, `WORK`. Can you explain what the driving logic is behind it?

Comment: As long as you don't modify directly the *input_list_of_strings*, i guess it'll always return the original list that you passed as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an interface to encapsulate how you want to split each string.

```
public static interface StringSplitter {
    public List<String> splitString(String s);
}
```

Then your 'getTiles' method would simply be:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getTiles(ArrayList<String> input,StringSplitter splitter) {

    int initSize = input.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < initSize; i++) {

        String source = input.remove(0); //Remove from head
        input.addAll(splitter.splitString(source)); //Add to end

    }

    return input;

}
```

**NOTE:**  This method modifies the original list, it can be easily adapted to simply copy the list if need be. Although, I like it better this way.

Since the exact process for splitting these words is unclear, I am going to guess that you want to keep splitting a word by three characters, unless that would leave only one character, then split by two - else don't split. So your default 'StringSplitter' would be:

```
public static final StringSplitter DEFAULT_SPLITTER = new StringSplitter() {

    @Override
    public List<String> splitString(String s) {
        List<String> subs = new ArrayList();
        while(!s.isEmpty()){
            int splitsize = 0;
            if(s.length() < 5) {
                if(s.length() == 4) {
                    splitsize = 2;
                } else {
                    splitsize = s.length();
                }
            } else {
                splitsize = 3;
            }
            subs.add(s.substring(0,splitsize));
            s = s.substring(splitsize);
        }
        return subs;
    }


};
```

Your main method would then be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<String> input_words = new ArrayList<String>();
    input_words.add("SCHOOLWORK");
    input_words.add("BALCONY");
    input_words.add("INSIST");
    input_words.add("SALTPETER");
    input_words.add("BOLTON");
    input_words.add("KITSCHY");
    input_words.add("CLIENTELE");
    System.out.print(getTiles(input_words),DEFAULT_SPLITTER); //Make sure to use DEFAULT_SPLITTER
}
```

Comment: Thank, that would be help a lot.

Comment: System.out.print(getTiles(input_words),DEFAULT_SPLITTER); //Have an error at getTiles(input_words) and it said: The method getTiles(ArrayList<String>, HW2.StringSplitter) in the type HW2 is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<String>).  I tried to fix it, but it didn't work to me.

Comment: You will need to make sure 'getTiles' takes in an ArrayList<String> and a 'StringSplitter' like the above example. Since this is homework, I am not sure how eager I am to help...

Comment: Ok, i figure out now. Thank a lot. How do I give you a credit for this help?

Answer (score 0):

First iterate through your `ArrayList<String>`. For each word in the ArrayList, split it into chunks. Your example above doesn't make much sense -- why is "SCHOOLWORK" split into "SCH", "OOL", "WO", "RK" and not "SCHOOL" and "WORK" ? Without understanding the logic behind your requirements, all we can give are general suggestions.

So, basically:

```
// iterate through the arraylist
ArrayList<String> allWords; // instantiate this
...
for(String word : allWords) {
    splitWord(word);
}
```

And create a method `splitWord(String)` that applies whatever logic you need aginst the word to split it up. I suggest looking into String's `substring()` method if you need words of a certain size.